How to reverse simulation in geometry nodes?
I wanna make this bottle start like small rocks floating from the ground and then come together to reveal the bottle so I used geometry nodes for that I followed a tutorial on YouTube but I couldn't understand how he reversed the simulation, Is there a way to reverse this simulation in geometry nodes so I can still control the simulation?



pls add link to tutorial. thx

Do you have any random process hidden in the group node Switch ? If yes, there is no way to backtrack in GN. Do you check that "he" is not just playing the animation back (using the left pointing arrow in the Timeline Editor) after playing it once forward ?

Yes, there is a node swish node, I don't have much experience in geometry nodes. I couldn't find what is the issue.
This is the tutorial :
https://youtu.be/R8M9G7gOzGM
This is the blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OH8JEaa99sftZd5RO9ayPR_BctCc3wwV/view?usp=drive_link
I hope you can help me with that, Thank you very much

Export as alembic then reimport an animate the frame override (Backwards).

But the animation will be very slow in the viewport because there are a lot of particles, Right?

We can not access your Blender file. Please remove authentication .

Sorry, I think it's working now

Sorry, I can not help you further as your file, probably from a higher version, is crashing my 3.6.8 Blender. I hope someone with a newer version might help you.

Oh, sorry for that, Yes, I made it in Blender 4.1. This is the link:
https://www.blender.org/download/releases/4-1/
I appreciate your help because I have been looking for the solution for more than 10 days now but I couldn't find anything. Thank you very much.

I went through the video and it seems to be the "Switch" boolean on the "Switch" group node that is controlling if points are moving away or towards their original position (time about 16:30).

This is the problem that I faced, When I uncheck the switch it just freezes rather than get back to its original position.
